# C# Cookie Error by Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, cookies

Hello i made a website who returns a serialized object. then i start a Request from a Fatclient who get the object and deserialize it.
When i start my page at the localhost i can easy get my serialized object and deserialize it. But if i publish it to the server i cant get back my object, i just get back a html page who says that i have to accept cookies.
I was searching for help about 6 hours.

My Serialization:

```
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";


        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(Response.OutputStream, ud);

        Response.End();
```

Deserialisation:

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient();



        String test = wb.DownloadString(url);

        byte[] b = wb.DownloadData(url);

        var mystream = new MemoryStream(b);

        BinaryFormatter binaryRead = new BinaryFormatter();


        Userdata userdata = (Userdata)binaryRead.Deserialize(mystream);;
        mystream.Close();
```

HTML error page content:

Cookie Error
Your browser does not accept cookies. Please enable cookies in your browser settings and try to access the application again.

Comment: Have you considered Web Services?

Answer (score 0):

because of a special component we use in the company to identify users its not possible to use a webservice for this appointment